# How to configure S3 bucket to allow POSTs to API Gateway without 405 error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have a static website hosted on AWS S3. The website can be accessed from either:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/example-bucket-name-to-avoid-spam/index.html
Or
http://example-bucket-name-to-avoid-spam.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

When a user completes the form and the captcha on the page and presses submit the following JavaScript is triggered:

```js
<script>
    // Replace the YOUR_API_ENDPOINT_URL with yours
    // It should look something like this:
    // https://qw324asdasd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/sendSms
    const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://fak3ur1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/sendSms';
    var messageDiv = document.getElementById('error-message')
    // Handle public api call
    document.getElementById('send-text').addEventListener('click', function () {
      const captchtaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse() || false
      const textMessage = document.getElementById('message').value
      const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phone-number').value

      if (!textMessage) {
        messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Remember to enter a message!'
        return false
      }

      if (!phoneNumber) {
        messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Don\'t forget to enter a phone number!'
        return false
      }

      if (!captchtaResponse) {
        messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Complete the Captcha please!'
        return false
      }

      const data = JSON.stringify({
        to: phoneNumber,
        message: textMessage,
        captcha: captchtaResponse
      })

      // post to API with native browser Fetch
      const getdata = fetch(API_ENDPOINT, {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: false,
      });

      getdata.then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          console.log('Response:', data);
          const body = JSON.parse(data.body);
          messageDiv.textContent = '';
          messageDiv.textContent = (body && body.message) ? body.message : '';
        });
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
      });
    });
  </script>
```

This successfully sends a POST through to the AWS API Gateway which processes the request correctly and sends a text with Twilio to the desired phone number.

I've also confirmed in Postman that the API Gateway/Lambda response itself is correctly coming back:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    "body": "{\"message\":\"Text message successfully sent!\",\"data\":{\"dateCreated\":\"2017-07-06T16:49:00.000Z\",\"dateUpdated\":\"2017-07-06T16:49:00.000Z\",\"from\":\"+13334445566\",\"body\":\"Sent from your Twilio trial account - test 5 with postman - looking at Lambda logs\"}}"
}
```

The issue happens after that POST is (presumably) sent to API Gateway. The static site redirects to an error page with this message when on the non-https url above:

```
405 Method Not Allowed

Code: MethodNotAllowed
Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
Method: POST
ResourceType: OBJECT
RequestId: IDSTRING123
HostId: Longhostidthing1237ygausdhasdgylh231ctidasd=
```

And this for the https url:

```
<Error>
<Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
<Message>
The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
</Message>
<Method>POST</Method>
<ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType>
<RequestId>IDSTRING123</RequestId>
<HostId>
Longhostidthing1237ygausdhasdgylh231ctidasd=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Initially I thought this was a CORS issue, but I've checked and rechecked several times the CORS policy on the bucket is very permissive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>0</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>0</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've also fiddled around with this a few times to confirm I was being as permissive as possible.

Finally, I've tried this incognito in Chrome, with cookies and all browsing data cleared in a separate profile, and all of the above with a plugin that disables CORS from the browser-side. None of these attempts appear to resolve my issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are over-complicating this. It sounds like you are posting something via JavaScript to API Gateway, but then also posting the same thing to S3? My guess is you need to simply prevent the default form post action from occurring since you are handling it via javascript.

Comment: @MarkB You were right! Prevent default or removing the post action fixed this.

Comment: @MarkB if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Mark B was correct.

"It sounds like you are posting something via JavaScript to API Gateway, but then also posting the same thing to S3? My guess is you need to simply prevent the default form post action from occurring since you are handling it via javascript."

Edit:
The easiest fix for this is to change this line:

```
document.getElementById('send-text').addEventListener('click', function () {
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById('send-text').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
```

And call `event.preventDefault()` on the subsequent line to prevent the default code from running and firing a post request.

Comment: For the benefit of future visitors, please edit this answer to show exactly how you fixed your form to behave as desired.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Updated.